# Cant make while() loop work when keep adding up random doubles until a particular distance is reached

Tags: java

I use a while() loop to keep adding up random doubles to x until x reaches a particular distance from origin. It stops running without any output. If I change the while() loop to 
while (Math.abs(x) == distance), it gives me output though not the right one I want. What is wrong with these code? Thanks for any of your input.

> ```
> while (Math.abs(x) != distance)
> {
>   randValue = (-1.0) + 2.0 * rand.nextDouble();
>   x = x + randValue;
>   move = move +1;
> }   
> System.out.println("After " + move + " moves X now at " + x);
> ```

Answer (score 6):

You're checking whether the value is *exactly* the distance required. You need to check whether it's reached *or exceeded* the required distance:

```
while (Math.abs(x) < distance)
```

In general, using `==` or `!=` with floating point values is a bad idea - after you've performed some operations, you'll often find that a value is *close* to the expected one, but not *exactly* right. If you want to check whether one value is "pretty much equal to" another one, you need to define a particular tolerance and check that. I don't think that's required in your situation though.

Comment: +1 As `randValue` will be `0.0` on average, it may take a long time to reach a specific distance.

Comment: Thank you. I tried (Math.abs(x) < distance) and it gave me an output: After 0 moves X now at 0.0 So it just skip the loop?

Comment: @oneStep: Well what's the value of `distance`?

Comment: My bad. I accidently enter a -2 for  distance. Thank you, Jon.